# How do I initialize values in a dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary, initialization

I have the following code:

```
import json
stats = dict()
for line in input :  # many many lines      
    for (field,value) in json.loads(line).iteritems() :
        stats.get(field,very_expensive_initializer(field)).add(value)
```

the problem is that Python is not lazy, so `very_expensive_initializer` is called once for each field in each line instead of once for each field. Right?

What is the right way to avoid this?

E.g., is this sufficiently idiomatic?

```
try :  s = stats[field]
except KeyError : s = stats[field] = very_expensive_initializer(field)
s.add(value)
```

Comment: shouldn't `stats = dict()` be `stats = dict`

Comment: @KDawG No it should not

Comment: @DavidHeffernan but wouldn't it cause a `TypeError: 'dict' object is not callable`

Comment: @KDawG no it wouldn't - unless you've shadowed it to be something else :)

Comment: This question isn't clear - do you only need to run the expensive initializer on one field always? Is it always the same field or does it move around?

Comment: @KDawG well yeah... if you're going to do something the OP isn't then you can make it do that I guess...

Comment: Your proposed 'idiomatic' version does something different. Your `.get()` call does *not* add the output of `very_expensive_initializer(field)` to the dictionary. Did you mean to use `.setdefault()` instead?

Comment: @JonClements oops shouldn't have posted that :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the default is expensive, test for the key:

```
item = stats.get(field) or very_expensive_initializer(field)
item.add(value)
```

or if `stats[field]` could be empty:

```
item = stats[field] if field in stats else very_expensive_initializer(field)
item.add(value)
```

Both `or` and a conditional expression evaluate lazily.

You can still make this a one-liner, but I am not sure you should. The above does match your original code.

Note that this does **not** add `very_expensive_initializer(field)` to `stats`! You could do that too:

```
if field not in stats:
    stats[field] = very_expensive_initializer(field)
```

or

```
try:
    item = stats[field]
except KeyError:
    item = stats[field] = very_expensive_initializer(field)
```

where you pick the first if `field` is *usually* not found in `stats`, the latter if `field` only *occasionally* not found in `stats`.

Your next option is to subclass `dict` and add a `__missing__` method:

```
class subclassed_dict(dict):
    def __missing__(self, key):
        item = self[key] = very_expensive_initializer(key)
        return item
```

then use that as `stats`:

```
stats = subclassed_dict()
```

Python will call `__missing__` whenever you try to access a key that's not yet there.

Demo:

```
>>> def very_expensive_initializer(field):
...     print 'Doing loads of work'
...     return set()
... 
>>> class subclassed_dict(dict):
...     def __missing__(self, key):
...         item = self[key] = very_expensive_initializer(key)
...         return item
... 
>>> stats = subclassed_dict()
>>> stats['foo'].add(2)
Doing loads of work
>>> stats['foo'].add(3)
>>> stats['foo'].add(4)
>>> stats['bar']
Doing loads of work
set([])
>>> stats['bar']
set([])
```

Comment: neither solution place the newly created value into the `stats` dict

Answer (score 1):

Wouldn't use exceptions here

```
if field not in stats:
    stats[field] = very_expensive_initializer(field)

s = stats[field]
```

Comment: Exceptions are an excellent choice if the field is *usually* present in the dictionary. See [Python Forgiveness vs. Permission and Duck Typing](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/a/175663)

Answer (score 0):

This seems better suited for a deserializer

http://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html#encoders-and-decoders

```
>>> import json
>>> def as_complex(dct):
...     if '__complex__' in dct:
...         return complex(dct['real'], dct['imag'])
...     return dct
...
>>> json.loads('{"__complex__": true, "real": 1, "imag": 2}',
...     object_hook=as_complex)
(1+2j)
>>> import decimal
>>> json.loads('1.1', parse_float=decimal.Decimal)
Decimal('1.1')
```